# nginx $uri is url decoded

Tags: nginx, rewrite, encoding

I am using **nginx** as reverse proxy and I have 2 rules like:

```
location ~ ^/indirect {
  rewrite ^/indirect(.*) /foobar$1;
}

location ~ ^/foobar {
  set $url http://example.com/something/index.php?var1=hello&access=$scheme://$host$uri;
  proxy_pass $url;
}
```

So, as you can see I'm passing the `$uri` variable as a parameter to the proxied page (the `$uri` variable is an nginx one, see the [`http core module`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule) documentation).

Problem is, if I visit `http://example.com/foobar/hello%20world`, the `$uri` variable contains  `/foobar/hello world` (as you see, the `%20` has been substituted with its url-decoded value, a space). And then, nginx returns http status code 400 (bad request) before executing the proxy_pass line (the backend there is not contacted).

There is also available the variable `$request_uri`, which holds the original request URI as issued by the client, so in this case it would hold the correct value, with the `%20` sequence. But I cannot use this because if a client goes through the `/indirect` path, `$request_uri` would contain `/indirect/...` while I want that the `access` param passed to the backend be always `/foobar/...`.

There are multiple `indirect`-like rules (this is for a DAV/calDAV/cardDAV server, and there are multiple clients out there that connect to multiple paths, so I need these `indirect`-like rules), so it is not feasible to do the `proxy_pass` there, and there are clients that go directly to the `/foobar` path.

So is there any way to get `$uri` without url-decoding it?

possible things that aren't acceptable:

- sending the request double-encoded, as the request may come from a client I have no control of
- specifying the final url multiple times in eacy indirect rule and also in the "direct" one, as it causes maintenance problems.

Comment: This whole setup is its own maintenance problem. So I'm not sure why you would reject a solution because it might be a "maintenance problem".

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, you are right, but if it's possible I don't want to make it even less maintainable

Comment: Finally I ended doing external 301 redirects from all the indirect uri's to the direct one, and only having the `proxy_pass` there. Should I answer my own question with this workaround?

Answer (score 3):

With `nginx/1.2.1`, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue of `%20`, once decoded into a space, of causing any [`400 Bad Request`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#ngx_http_error_400_page) within nginx; perhaps that's coming from upstream?

Regardless, it is actually not that difficult to use the finite-state automaton that is provided through the [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) directive to stop `$uri` from containing the decoded request, yet still perform all sorts of transformations of the request.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637

The idea is that when you change `$uri` in place, it doesn't get re-decoded.  And, as you know, we do already have the undecoded one in `$request_uri`.  What's left is to simply set one to the other, and call it a day.

```
server {
    listen 2012;
    location /a {
        rewrite ^/a(.*) /f$1 last;
    }
    location /i {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/i(.*) /f$1 last;
        return 400; #if the second rewrite won't match
    }
    location /f {
        set $url http://127.0.0.1:2016/s?v=h&a=$scheme://$host$uri;
        proxy_pass $url;
    }
}

server {
    listen 2016;
    return 200 $request_uri\n;
}
```

And, yes, the `rewrite ^ $request_uri;` part above does do the trick:

```
% echo localhost:2012/{a,i,f}/h%20w | xargs -n1 curl
/s?v=h&a=http://localhost/f/h w
/s?v=h&a=http://localhost/f/h%20w
/s?v=h&a=http://localhost/f/h w
%
```

(If you want the "direct" thing to not be decoded, either, then it'll probably be easiest to just make it an "indirect" as well.)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found is to use the [HttpSetMiscModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule#set_escape_uri) like so:

```
location ~
 ^/indirect {
  set_escape_uri $key $1;
  rewrite ^/indirect(.*) /foobar$key;
}

location ~ ^/foobar {
  set_escape_uri $key $uri;
  set $url http://example.com/something/index.php?var1=hello&access=$scheme://$host$key;
  proxy_pass $url;
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way (without having to compile nginx with external modules, because I don't have root access) please let me know!

Comment: If you're still interested, see my answer above/below, and/or at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637.